# How can i show a badge notification in a button using devexpress mvvm ?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, notifications, devexpress, badge

[Notification Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEuLj.png)

i wanna add a badge notification to that button , using Devexpress MVVM Architecture

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have tried and try to read about [ask]

Comment: i don't know from where to start that's the issue

Comment: In that case, it's worth to do some research yourself. Start with a visual representation of the badge notification button in XAML. Then add some MVVM properties to interact with it. Try to duckduckgo a bit around

Comment: ive already done some research before asking the question, ive found this https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.VisualEffects.AdornerUIManager.class and https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.VisualEffects.Badge.class ,  but i dont know how to implement it

Comment: I am not a devexpress expert, but the article is about a winforms control. The thing is: winforms is totally different than WPF. Maybe that would be a starting point. Do you have any XAML in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches of accomplishing the task you described.

**Simple**(for predefined badge):
Create the `ShowXXX` property at the ViewModel side and bind this property to the [Badge.Visible](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.VisualEffects.AdornerElement.Visible.property) property of the specific badge created and designed earlier in the WinForms designer:

```
// ViewModel side
public class ViewModel {
    public virtual bool ShowAlarm { get; set; }
}
...
// View side
var fluent = mvvmContext.OfType<ViewModel>();
fluent.SetBinding(alarmBadge, b => b.Visible, x => x.ShowAlarm);
```

**Complex**(for dynamically generated badges):

Create custom implementation of the  [INotificationService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114024/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Design-time-Support/Control-based-Services#notification) based on the  [AdornerUIManager's](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.VisualEffects.AdornerUIManager.class) component API. This way requires some coding, but allows you to handle any scenarios. I suggest you contact the DevExpress support [directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) if you're running into a trouble with this way.